# "undefined is not a function" when trying to use react-mde markdown editor

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I am trying to use react-mde as seen here https://github.com/andrerpena/react-mde

But I am getting the error "undefined is not a function" in my setup for some reason and I cannot figure out why.

```
import * as React from "react";
import ReactMde from "react-mde";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import * as Showdown from "showdown";
import "react-mde/lib/styles/css/react-mde-all.css";

const converter = new Showdown.Converter({
  tables: true,
  simplifiedAutoLink: true,
  strikethrough: true,
  tasklists: true,
});

function NormEdit() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState("**Hello world!!!**");
  const [selectedTab, setSelectedTab] =
    (React.useState < "write") | ("preview" > "write");
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <ReactMde
        value={value}
        onChange={setValue}
        selectedTab={selectedTab}
        onTabChange={setSelectedTab}
        generateMarkdownPreview={(markdown) =>
          Promise.resolve(converter.makeHtml(markdown))
        }
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default NormEdit;
```

this is my code, and below is the line that the error is occuring on

```
const [selectedTab, setSelectedTab] =
    (React.useState < "write") | ("preview" > "write");
```

any help would be much appreciated =]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selectedTab useState needs to be something more like this:

```
const [selectedTab, setSelectedTab] = React.useState<"write" | "preview">("write");
```

This part `<"write" | "preview">` looks like typescript and means that the selectedTab state is only ever allowed to be a string that's either "write" or "preview".

Comment: This will only work with typescript so I get an error

Comment: Take out the typing then and have it be `React.useState("write")`.

Comment: ```const [selectedTab, setSelectedTab] = React.useState("write");``` seemed to solve it as you suggested, removing the other parts should not effect the rest of the code right?

Comment: Nope, if you aren't using TypeScript it should be just fine.